# Vide html5 poster(background-image) cover doesn´t working

Tags: html, css, html5-video, background-image, cover

i have an issue an one question about the html5´s video.

1.The issue ist that i can not have a cover background-image if i don´t put the  tag, i can see the background in 'cover' but after insert the video the image changes the size.

Hier an example:

http://codepen.io/TamZam/pen/rrLmqm

HTML:

```
<video poster="http://ideasparadecoracion.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/lego-decoraci%C3%B3n.jpg" controls>
```

2. Second i have a cuestion, can i have a bottom (personalized) above the video before to start and after do click star the video (i think that i can do it with javascript)? The question is how have the bottom above, the javascript tiel i know how do it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: For Issue 1: Probably your poster size and video sizes are not same for that while loading image it takes the image's size.

Comment: For the first question i have the solution:  **object-fit: cover**. Thanks :)